# Error while validating constraint

Tags: odoo-10

when I am writing in a field in Arabic language and save the file, Odoo raises this exception:

> > Error while validating constraint
> >     123
> >     The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Comment: Please share your stacktrace and code here.

Comment: Error while validating constraint 123 The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect